# Updating aura attribute in 1 aura:iteration does not reflect the changes in another aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I've created a simple lightning app which has an `aura:attribute` of type `Object[]` with 3 objects in it. I'm binding their `selected` property to a `lightning:input` of type `checkbox`. When I update the value of any of these object properties and print them within the `aura:iteration`, the values update as and when I check/uncheck my checkbox. But these new values do not get reflected if I try to print them again in another `aura:iteration`.

Here's the sample app code I've used to try to reproduce this problem:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="val" type="Object[]" default="[{name: 'First', selected: true}, {name: 'Second', selected: false}, {name: 'Third', selected: true}]" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.val}" var="i">
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" value="test" label="{!i.name}" checked="{!i.selected}" />
        <div>
            {!i.selected}
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
   <div> 
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.val}" var="j">
       <div>
           {!j.name + ': ' + j.selected}
       </div>
   </aura:iteration>
 </div>     
</aura:application>
```

Here's how the app looks when the page loads:
[image]

and here's how the app looks after I check the second checkbox (notice how `Second` becomes `true` in the above section but stays `false` in the below section, even if they're referring to the same attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has to with how aura:valueChange works. It can't detect attributes on an object changing, only the object itself. One simple way to get this to work is to force an aura:valueChange event directly:

```
<lightning:input onchange="{!c.handleChange}" type="checkbox" value="test" label="{!i.name}" checked="{!i.selected}" />

 handleChange: function(component, event, helper) {
   component.set("v.val", component.get("v.val"));
 }
```

This will cause the rest of the component to see the new data.

Comment: Hey, this works, thanks. But this seems like an issue with `aura:iteration` since as a developer, I would expect this to work without this workaround. Or do you feel otherwise?

Comment: @ChiragBhatia-chirag64 No, I wish it worked as we expected. However, it doesn't, so for now, this will get you where you need to go.